# 'join' parameter in Dataframe.update()

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I am trying to update a dataframe with the other. I noticed that 'update' only updates the values at matching columns and doesn't add new columns from the other frame. Anyway to perform both functions: updating the values and adding a new column?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [400, 500, 600]})
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [4, 5, 6],'C': [7, 8, 9]})
df.update(new_df, join='left')
```

Updated `df` doesn't have 'C' column. Why so? What does exactly `join='left'` does?

Answer (score 0):

`join='left'` is the default and only currently (as of Pandas 0.23) implemented mode.  As per [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

> Only left join is implemented, keeping the index and columns of the original object.

So you'll need to do your task in two steps: update and separately add new columns--either manually or using `df.join()`:

```
df.join(new_df, rsuffix='_new')
```

Or just use a loop through `new_df.columns` and check `if column in df`.

Comment: Can you please explain how I can add that column 'C' with DataFrame.merge()?

Comment: @UmarAftab: I updated my answer--you'd use join not merge actually.